# Why is my if statement not working even when true? If statement is inside function, but works outside a function

Tags: function, if-statement, python-3.6

```
def PER_Calc(PERatio,PECom):
    print("I am here")
    print(PERatio,"inside")
    if PERatio >= 0 and PERatio <= 18:
        PECom = 10
        PERatio = PERatio + 2
    return PECom

PECom = 0
PERatio = 18
PER_Calc(PERatio,PECom)
print(PERatio)
print(PECom)
```

RESULTS ARE

```
I am here
18 inside
18
0
```

SHOULD BE

```
I am here
18 inside
20
10
```

Comment: Are you sure your if statement is "not working"? Are you sure you didn't just misunderstand variable scoping rules? What debugging have you performed so far?

Comment: You don't assign the returned value (and only returned one of them anyway).

Comment: I could care less about the PERatio. I only want the value of PECom returned. I put the "I am here" and PERatio value inside my function to see if I was getting there.

Comment: Now put one inside the `if` too, to check your assumption that it is not being reached.

Comment: _"I [couldn't] care less about the PERatio."_ Yet, you're complaining that its value is not what you wanted it to be?

Comment: I tried the If statement outside a function and it gets me the correct results.

Comment: Do what I said to do.

Comment: I did. It shows that I'm executing it True, but even though I set PECom=10, it appears my return PECom isn't getting returned

Comment: Right, so we can forget the whole "if statement not working" thing, because clearly _it is_. Instead, focus on how modifying variables inside a function affects them _outside_ of the function. To do this, first review the chapter in your Python book about scoping rules and about what happens to things that you `return`. These are language basics that you simply need to re-study.